# input type="date" set a default value to date today

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I set an input type="date" value set to default value equals date today?

this is my HTML code, what's the best way to do it?

```html
<div class="form-group col-6">
    <label for="inputEmail4">Start date</label>
        <input type="date" value="fsd" id="startdateId" class="form-control" required>
 </div>
```

Comment: this one line should wort => `document.getElementById('startdateId').valueAsDate = new Date();`

Comment: You can simply try this ```document.getElementById('startdateId').value = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)```

Comment: If you are using jQuery then ```$('#startdateId').val(new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10));```

Comment: Hi Thank you! I have updated the code to

     <input type="text" value="fsd" id="startdateId" class="form-control" required>

then apply 
$("#startdateId").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());

Answer (score 5):

try it

```js
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();

if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

var today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

document.getElementById("startdateId").value = today;
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-6">
  <label for="inputEmail4">Start date</label>
  <input type="date" value="fsd" id="startdateId" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add explanation. What did you do. Why did you do it?

Comment: this one line should work => `document.getElementById('startdateId').valueAsDate = new Date();`

Answer (score 0):

Like any HTML input field, the browser will leave it empty unless a default value is specified with the value attribute.

Unfortunately, HTML5 doesn't provide a way of specifying 'today' in the value attribute. You need Javascript to do so.

```js
document.getElementById('startdateId').value = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-6">
  <label for="inputEmail4">Start date</label>
     <input type="date" value="fsd" id="startdateId" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

Comment: this one line should work => `document.getElementById('startdateId').valueAsDate = new Date();`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping my code also works its JS man thousand to ways to do the same things.

Comment: Nice effort - i did not said that your code does not work. Just added to show that that more simple then a slice and isoString. :)